# Combine integer and string in array and save to a text file

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I have several numpy arrays, all but one contain integers. I want to combine them into a single array and save it in a .txt file. This very last line causes me troubles, since I'm trying to combine integer with string:

```
import numpy as np


specimen = np.array(['one1', 'two2', 'three3'])

outpath = '/some_folder/'

M1_x_list = np.array([1,2,3])
M1_y_list = np.array([2,3,4])
M1_z_list = np.array([4,5,6])


ALL_OUTPUT = np.asarray([specimen, M1_x_list, M1_y_list, M1_z_list]).T
print ALL_OUTPUT

np.savetxt(outpath+'test.txt', (ALL_OUTPUT), delimiter='\t', newline='\n', header='specimen \t x \t y \t z\t ', footer='')
```

My expected output would be:

```
['one1' '1' '2' '4']
['two2' '2' '3' '5']
['three3' '3' '4' '6']
```

Comment: After you line with `ALL_OUTPUT = np.asarray([specimen, M1_x_list, M1_y_list, M1_z_list]).T` your array convetred to `str`. You could check `dtype`

Comment: Thanks. I've stumbled upon dtype before, but I can't understand how to implement it in my case.

Comment: Could you attach your expected output?

Comment: Line one: one1 1 2 4, Line two:  two2 2 3 5, Line 3: three3 4 5 6 (sorry don't know how to break lines in comments.

Comment: It'll be better to update your question with your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Define int as string?

`int1=str( /*insert whatever your integer is here*/ )`

Then add `int1` to the array.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `dtype` in your array list. Add `dtype=int32` after the line.